# Passing an optional parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a PowerShell script `CSV2JSON.ps1` with the following code:

```
param(
        [String]$FieldSeparator=",",
        [String[]]$Header
)

$input | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $FieldSeparator -Header $Header | ConvertTo-JSON
```

If I call it as `.\CSV2JSON.ps1 -FieldSeparator "|" -Header "name|age"` it works fine. However, if I drop the optional parameter `Header`, the `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet complains that `Header` cannot be null:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Header'.
The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
```

I don't want to pass the `-Header` parameter at all, if it's not provided. Is there a neat way to pass on optional parameters without getting into `If` statements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has suggested [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable.

[`$PSBoundParameters`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/04/06/checking-for-bound-parameters/) is a hashtable containing all the parameter arguments that was passed to the command.

Simply rename the `$FieldSeparator` parameter to `$Delimiter` and you're good to go.
You can provide the `FieldSeparator` name as a parameter alias if needed:

```
param(
        [Alias('FieldSeparator')]
        [String]$Delimiter=",",
        [String[]]$Header
)

$input | ConvertFrom-Csv @PSBoundParameters | ConvertTo-JSON
```

If the `-Header` parameter is omitted when executing the calling function/script, it'll also be omitted from the call to `ConvertFrom-Csv`

Comment: ++ - without a doubt the simplest and most elegant solution.

Comment: It is elegant. However it forces the two functions to use parameters with the same name, and doesn't work if `@PSBoundParameters` contains additional parameters that are not accepted by the function being called.

Comment: @Gildor `ConvertFrom-Csv` supports Common Parameters, so that shouldn't be a problem in this case :-) If you have a wrapper function with *additional* parameters, you can always clone `$PSBoundParameters` and modify the entries before splatting

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen true in this case, but does not work in my scenario because the called function is another user-defined function... :(

Comment: @Gildor That can be addressed as well - feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you're having trouble :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. I used briantist's solution below. It is a bit lengthy compared to yours but it would be much clearer to the reader what parameters are passed to the function.

Answer (score 4):

Martin Brandl is right, you must use an `if`, but I would recommend combining it with [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) so that you only make your call once:

```
param(
        [String]$FieldSeparator=",",
        [String[]]$Header
)

$params = @{
    Delimeter = $FieldSeparator
}
if ($Header) {
    $params.Header = $Header
}

$input | ConvertFrom-Csv @params | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have another option based on the feedback from Martin. This works well when the parameter names match:

```
param(
    $Path,
    $Delimiter,
    $Header
)

$params = @{}
$MyInvocation.BoundParameters.Keys | Where {$_} |
    % {$params.Add($_, (Get-Variable $_).Value )}

Import-Csv @params
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **no**. You have to leverage an `if` statement. Such would work for boolean or switch values, example:

```
param(
        [String]$FieldSeparator=",",
        [String[]]$Header,
        [switch]$Compress        
)

$input | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $FieldSeparator | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress:$Compress
```

**Note**: You may be able to do it using `MyInvocation.BoundParameter` and splatting but I doubt this will make your script more readable.

Comment: he's trying to drop header?

Comment: he wants to exclude the header parameter if its not passed to the script

Comment: i guess i don't really understand what he's doing ;)