# How do I pass a string as a non-string to a command in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to conditionally add parameters to a command I am invoking in `powershell`. However, when I try, my parameter gets passed as a string. I can’t figure out how to pass it as an identifier instead.

This is my attempt so far:

```
$readParams = $(if ("2".Equals("2")) {"-AsSecureString"})
read-host 'Prompt' $readParams
```

The output I get is:

```
Prompt -AsSecureString:
```

I want to be able to set `$readParams` differently depending on conditions. If the condition is true get this behavior:

```
read-host 'Prompt' -AsSecureString
```

and if the condition is false get this behavior:

```
read-host 'Prompt'
```

I only want to write `read-host` once in my program.

How do I specify the argument dynamically without passing it as a string which causes it to become part of the prompt instead of passed as an identifier-style parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549297/passing-an-optional-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prepare *multiple* parameters in advance, use the *splatting* technique described in [Mike Shepard's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52371696/45375), which uses a hashtable whose keys are named for the target cmdlet's parameters and also works with *switch* parameters (as an alternative to conditionally omitting an entry named for the switch parameter, include it unconditionally and assign `$True` to emulate *passing* the switch, and `$False` to emulate *omitting* it<sup>[1]</sup>).

---

To expand on [Jacob Colvin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52371722/45375):

For a *switch* parameter such as `-AsSecureString` (an optional Boolean parameter without argument), the challenge is that a switch's value is normally *implied* by its *presence* (`$True`) vs. its *absence* (`$False`)<sup>[2]</sup>.

However, there *is* a syntax that allows passing the value *explicitly*, namely by **appending `:<expr>` *directly* to the switch name**, where `<expr>` is an expression whose value is converted to a Boolean; to illustrate with the automatic `$True` and `$False` variables:

- `-AsSecureString:$True` ... same as just `-AsSecureString`
- `-AsSecureString:$False` ... usually the same as *not passing* `-AsSecureString`<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore, you can solve your problem as follows, using an expression (enclosed in `(...)`) *directly*, with no need for aux. variable `$readParams`:

```
 Read-Host 'Prompt' -AsSecureString:('2' -eq '2')
```

<sup>* Obviously, the expression value shouldn't be *invariant* in real-life use.

* `'2' -eq '2'` is PowerShell's equivalent of `"2".Equals("2")`, though note that PowerShell's `-eq` is case-*insensitive* by default, so, strictly speaking, `-ceq` would be the closer analog.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] On occasion, `-SomeSwitch:$False` has different semantics from *omitting* the switch altogether, notably when overriding preference variables ad hoc. For instance, if `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` is in effect to make all cmdlets produce verbose output by default, you can use `-Verbose:$False` on individual commands to suppress it.</sup>

<sup>[2] Strictly speaking, a parameter *variable* inside a cmdlet/advanced function that represents a switch *parameter* is of type `[switch]`([`System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.switchparameter)); however, instances of this type effectively *behave like* Booleans.

Somewhat confusingly, and against what the documentation says, the type's `.IsPresent` property reflects the *effective Boolean value* of the switch (on or off, loosely speaking), and *not* whether the switch was *explicitly passed* by the user.</sup>

Comment: To even use splatting (@MikeShepard’s answer), I have to know that optional switches are actually boolean parameters. This is a comprehensive and helpful answer. For my case, the explicit switch syntax makes the most sense.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @binki. I was speaking somewhat loosely with respect to whether switch parameters are Booleans, but in practice you can treat them as such; please see footnote [2] for details.

Answer (score 5):

The feature you're looking for is called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).  It allows you to present a hashtable to a command and have it interpreted as parameters.

```
$readParams=@{}
if("2".Equals("2")) {
  $readParams["AsSecureString"]=$true
}
read-host 'Prompt' @readParams
```

Comment: Easier `$readParams=@{AsSecureString=("2".Equals("2"));Prompt='Prompt'}` and `$input = Read-Host @readParams` (+1)

Comment: That's fair.  Either way, splatting is the way to go.  :-)

Comment: @LotPings Stop using `$input` as a variable name.  It's an automatic variable and should be treated as read-only.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thanks for the reminder ;-) Some of these `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables` are just too tempting.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the switch to true or false depending on the condition:

```
$readParams = $(if ("2".Equals("2")) {$true} else {$false})
read-host 'Prompt' -AsSecureString:$readParams
```